# Replace a text in Word doc with a picture from a database c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I know how to get a picture from a databse as Byte array :

```
string query2 = "SELECT Logo FROM Client WHERE CompanyName = '"+CN+"' ;";
using (SqlCeCommand command1 = new SqlCeCommand(query2, connection))
{
    try
    {
        SqlCeDataReader reader3 = command1.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader3.Read())
        {
            byte[] byteArray = (byte[])reader3["Logo"];
            Image img = byteArrayToImage(byteArray);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception excf)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(excf.Message);
    }
}
```

I know how to replace some text by an image using the image's path :

```
var kword = "#Logo#";
var sel = app.Selection;
sel.Find.Text = kword;
sel.Find.Execute(Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceOne);
sel.Range.Select();
sel.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath);
```

But I don't know (and I realy can't figure out how to replace some text by the image I got in my database.

I'm sure there is something obvious that I'm missing but I didn't find the answer on google.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c2a89c07-f8e4-4b3b-9db9-251dc042564b/adding-a-image-from-a-byte-array-into-an-ooxml-word-document?forum=oxmlsdk

Please visit the above link.. It might be of some help on the above Issue.

Comment: I know how to add a picture, I just want to replace some text by my picture.. I'm sure it's so simple but I really can't find a proper solution.